# Laravel view counter (PUT 405 (Method Not Allowed) ) problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to make view counter for my course page  using Ajax but it seems not working well

this is a hidden form

```
 <form style="display:none;" method="POST" action="{{route('view_counter',$courses->id)}}">                             
   @csrf
   @method('PUT')                                   
   <input type="text" id="postVisitCount" name="visitCount" value="{{$courses->visit_count}}">
   <input value="send" type="submit">
</form>
```

this is a ajax code

```
<script>

let visitCount=document.getElementById('postVisitCount').value;
let visitCountPlusOne=parseInt(visitCount)+1;
document.getElementById('postVisitCount').value=visitCountPlusOne;
let $formVar=$('form');

$.ajax({        
    url: $formVar.prop('{{route('view_counter',$courses->id)}}'),       
    method: 'PUT',      
    data: $formVar.serialize(),
    
});
```

this is a route for course

```
Route::namespace('course')->prefix('/courses')->group(function()
    {

      Route::get('/','CoursesController@index')->name('all_courses');
      Route::post('/comment','CommentsController@store')->name('comment');
      Route::post('/answer','QuizesController@store')->name('answer');
      Route::put('/view/{put}','CoursesController@update')->name('view_counter'); // THIS PAGE GETS SOME INFORMATION USING AJAX
     
        
      Route::prefix('/{course:slug}')->group(function()
      {
          
        Route::get('/','CoursesController@view')->name('view'); // AJAX CODE IS IN THIS FILE
        Route::get('/quiz/{quiz:slug}','QuizesController@quiz')->name('quiz_view');                 
        Route::get('/{lesson:slug}','LessonsController@lesson')->name('action');
    
      });
      
      

    });
```

this is update function

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $course=Course::find($id);
        $course->visit_count=$request->input('visitCount');
        $course->save();
        return back();

    }
```

The errors that I am getting:

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/beginner
Request Method: PUT
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

When I try this it gives me error put method is not allowed!. I really stuck with this for a while.

Comment: Why is the request URL `.../courses/beginner` and the route is `Route::put('/view/{put}','CommentsController@update')->name('view_counter');` ?

Comment: oh sorry I changed to actual controller

Comment: Also why are you using `back();` try removing that

Comment: I did try but still same error remains

Comment: Your path doesn't make sense the request URL and the named route `view_counter` url are different

Comment: Most browsers can't send `PUT` methods and are restricted to just `GET` and `POST`.

Try changing the method to `POST`, but leave your `_method` element in the data array to spoof the request method. Change method to `POST`

Comment: I actually tried that and did work

Comment: I think problem is coming from Routing but I don't understand the point yet

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#increment-and-decrement Use that on show/index controller for when user show the page. Don't need form etc.

Comment: I need the form

Comment: why form required? visit counter can be done very easily this way @AkromNumonov